# Json is not correct \" iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json

Hi i'm trying to convert a NSMutable to JSON String and this is my code:

```
-(NSString *) buildFeedback {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3 *notificationDB;
    NSString *result = @"";
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"feedbacks.db"];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &notificationDB)==SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM FEEDBACKS"];
        const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(notificationDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *feedbackText = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSMutableDictionary *feedback = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [feedback setObject:feedbackText forKey:@"content"];
                NSMutableDictionary *feedbacks = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [feedbacks setObject:feedback forKey:@"feedback"];



                NSError *error;
                NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:feedbacks
                                                                   options:0
                                                                     error:&error];

                if (! jsonData) {
                    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
                } else {
                     if ([result length])
                      result = [result stringByAppendingString:@","];

                    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    result = [result stringByAppendingString:jsonString];
                }

            }
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(notificationDB);
    return result;

}
```

And in my rails server i'm getting this:

Parameters: {"feedbacks"=>"{\"feedback\":{\"content\":\"X<

My problem is how do i do a real json string without the escapes (\").

Comment: That's not valid JSON at all, due to the `=>`s.

Comment: It is the parameters from the controller, it has already parsed by Rails i guess. My problem are the \"

Comment: If you have a solution, please don't post it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routine is creating a `NSDictionary` with a key of `feedback` (and you're putting the `content` dictionary underneath that), making a string of that, and appending that to the results. You would then appear to be taking that and making a dictionary with an object keyed by `feedbacks` with that string.

Instead, you should return the `NSData`, and have your `while` loop add objects to a `NSMutableArray`, which you encode at the end of the loop.

---

I'd suggest a number of things:

1. If your `sqlite3` calls fail, examine `sqlite3_errmsg`.
2. Don't forget to do `sqlite3_finalize` when you're done iterating through your results.
3. If open failed, you're still trying to close database; move `sqlite3_close` inside the `if` block of a successful open.
4. Move JSON creation out of the `while` loop.
5. Use a `NSMutableArray` instead of a `NSMutableDictionary` for `feedbacks` (and move its declaration outside of the `while` loop).

Thus:

```
-(NSData *) buildFeedback
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3 *notificationDB;
    NSData *jsonData = nil;
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"feedbacks.db"];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &notificationDB)==SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *querySql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM FEEDBACKS"];
        const char* query_sql = [querySql UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare(notificationDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

            NSMutableArray *feedbacks = [NSMutableArray array]; // move this outside the `for` loop and make array

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *feedbackText = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSMutableDictionary *feedback = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [feedback setObject:feedbackText forKey:@"content"];
                [feedbacks addObject:feedback];
            }

            // move the JSON stuff outside of the loop

            NSError *error;
            jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:feedbacks
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];

            if (!jsonData) {
                NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
            } else {

                // if you want to look at this for diagnostic purposes, that's fine,
                // but this function should return the `NSData`

                NSLog(@"jsonString = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            }

            // don't forget to finalize

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog (@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(notificationDB));
        }

        // this should go inside the "open" == SQLITE_OK block

        sqlite3_close(notificationDB);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_open failed!", __FUNCTION__);
    }

    return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: I've done that but my problem is that this is a Dictionary, so i can't have multiple objects "feedback" in it. I had a simple solution that was adding an index but that's not good. My goal is this:
feedbacks {
      feedback {
         content :something
      }
      feedback {
         content :something
      }
}

Comment: @lfmarques2 you really should be using an array for your list of `feedback` objects, not a dictionary. Then you can add you `feedback` entries without any problems.

Comment: I have a lot of experience in java and some other languages but right now i'm a noob in Objective-C/iOS. How could i do that? I put [feedbacks setObject:feedback forKey:@"feedback"]; and i get {"feedback":{"content":... How can i do it with an array?

Comment: @lfmarques2 It looks like you solved your immediate problem, but there are a number of little issues in your code. See my revised answer with code sample.

Comment: You're awesome. Usually i'm a lot more careful with my code but now i'm on a really tight schedule and my approach is basically if i want to do something look for an exemple and adapt it. Thanks a lot for your time and patience.